# Radio input in directive not working with button-label

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I created following directive, which works fine as intended:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('radioselect', radioselect);

radioselect.$inject = [];

function radioselect() {
    var html =
        '<div class="form-group">' +
        '   <label>{{title}}</label>' +
        '   <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm pull-right" data-toggle="buttons">' +
        //'     <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-class="{\'active\': model === true }">' +
        '           <input type="radio" name="{{groupname}}" autocomplete="off" ng-model="model" ng-value="true"> Ja' +
        //'     </label>' +
        //'     <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-class="{\'active\': model === false }">' +
        '           <input type="radio" name="{{groupname}}" autocomplete="off" ng-model="model" ng-value="false"> Nein' +
        //'     </label>' +
        //'     <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-class="{\'active\': model === undefined || model === null }">' +
        '           <input type="radio" name="{{groupname}}" autocomplete="off" ng-model="model" ng-value="null"> Alle' +
        //'     </label>' +
        '   </div>' +
        '</div>';
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: html,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            groupname: '@',
            title: '@'
        }
    };        

    return directive;
}
```

Since I am using bootstrap, I want to use buttons instead of checkboxes, so I inserted labels as shown in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/ (uncomment the commented lines).

But then it's not working. The design is working, but the binding does not seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is not working??

Comment: The binding. If I click on the button, the value is not changed. But if I click on the inputs, everything works fine.